# How to install Nintendo Emulator gfceu on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: software-installation, games, emulation

On ubuntu 18.04 we've got the NES emulator in the repositories gfceu...

**Ubuntu 18.04**

```
$ apt search gfceu
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
gfceu/bionic,bionic,now 0.6.1-0ubuntu4 all [installed]
  Graphical front-end using GTK2 for the FCE Ultra NES emulator
$
```

However on Ubuntu 20.04 it doesn't exist...

**Ubuntu 20.04**

```
$ apt search gfceu
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
$
```

So how do we install it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways to install it on Ubuntu 20.04

**1) Via snaps...**

```
$ sudo snap install fceux-gui --candidate
```

That installs it from the candidate channel.

**Pros this method:**

The maintainer will always get to update this one to the latest if there are any changes and it won't require any dependencies on Ubuntu packages.

**Cons this method:**

Problem installing it this way is that if you have all your ROMs in some directory outside your home folder then you won't be able to get to it because of snap's isolation security.  You will have to put the ROMs somewhere in your home directory.

Soft links will also not work.

If you have a massive library of ROMs on some mount for example at /mnt/romdisk/...  Well you'll struggle to get to it.  If this setup is for your kids, well it fails the KISS ideal!  (Keep it simple and stupid!)

**2) Via apt in the official ubuntu repos...**

```
$ sudo apt install -y fceu
```

**Pros this method:**

It works, it is native, it gets to any path/mount on your PC.
It just works!

**Cons this method:**

Well you're stuck with the repo version until either you upgrade to the next future release of Ubuntu or if through some miracle Ubuntu guys decide to upgrade to the latest version, if there is one!

**Conclusion**
My preference is the repo version point 2 above.  Just works, KISS for the kids, get's to any mount where you have a library of Nintendo games.
Honestly, especially now in the middle of a Coronavirus pandemic, this Nintendo emulator with all the ROMs available free on the internet is a God send!  They play while I work!

**Tip:** If you have an old XBOX controller, it works with it.  But works best with most games if you don't try and configure the left thumbstick but program instead the bottom left directional-pad.  Then just use the same A and B buttons!

Enjoy!

Comment: Can't edit, because StackExchange expects me to change at least 6 characters, but the name to install by apt is fceux not fceu.

Answer (score 1):

The best way I found to use snap, because it has later version than ubuntu repos.

```
sudo snap install fceux-gui --candidate
```

Than, with 20.04 I have problem "Cannot access file /usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf"
And I have found solution, to to accept pulse in snap settings and turn fceux use pulse via SDL settings:

sudo snap connect fceux-gui:pulseaudio :pulseaudio

than run (or create shortcut with this string):

SDL_AUDIODRIVER=pulse fceux-gui

(or you could set for it environment)